# Woocommerce Stocking Issue

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, paypal

I got an issue with the Woocommerce stocking system. The issue arises when a product stock is reduced to 1, after that every time a customer buys that particular product, the stock does not turn to 0 and hence makes it 'out of stock'.

We've been trying to fix this but never succeeded.

For the payment system we are using Paypal, Bank Transfer (manual), and our local Indonesian payment gateway called Midtrans.

We have tried contacting Paypal which we suspected as the problem, as we keep getting IPN error notifications. I am not too sure yet if Paypal is related to this stocking issue.

Answer (score 0):

Some of WooCommerce's PayPal payment methods do use IPN to mark orders as successfully paid, so that could be related. You should work on ensuring your IPN listener is functioning properly and able to receive messages from PayPal without error.

Alternatively, there are various alternate PayPal plugins for WooCommerce that you can try, and some do not depend on the legacy IPN service.